# Fix Javascript error

Tags: javascript

```
Function findMax(objects) {
    var values = [];

    // We parse each object in array
    _.each(objects, parseObject());

    function parseObject(object) {
        // We add a value from an object to values array
        values.push(object.value);
    }

    // We pick the maximum value
    return Math.Max(values);
}
```

How to fix errors in code ?

Comment: This was quite easy to spot, but in future you should put the actual error in your question too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Answer (score 1):

`Function` is not the identifier you're looking for. It's `function`.

Also, you are executing `parseObject` immediately. I assume you wanted to pass it in as a callback to `_.each`:

```
function findMax(objects) {
    var values = [];

    // We parse each object in array
    _.each(objects, parseObject);

    function parseObject(object) {
        // We add a value from an object to values array
        values.push(object.value);
    }

    // We pick the maximum value
    return Math.Max(values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`_.each` function accepts a function reference as a second parameter, instead of it you invoked the function.

Replace `_.each(objects, parseObject());` with `_.each(objects, parseObject);`